# Input value changing the display of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a div dissapearing after a X value on the input, i can make the value changing when clicked on a div, but the div i want to hide, doesn't hide.. looks like it doesn't update when changing the value of the input.

```
$("#ticket-plus").on('click', function() {
  $("#naenae").val( +$("#naenae").val() + 5 );
});

if ($("#naenae").val() == 10) {
  $("#badge-one > div").hide();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to put the last three lines inside the `click` handler.

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#ticket-plus").on('click', function() {
  $("#naenae").val( +$("#naenae").val() + 5 );
if ($("#naenae").val() == 10) {
  $("#badge-one > div").hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `parseInt(` befor adding the value

```
$("#ticket-plus").on('click', function() {
 $("#naenae").val( parseInt($("#naenae").val()) + 5 );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `keyup()` or `keydown()` event :

```
$("#naenae").keyup(function() {
    if ($("#naenae").val() == 10) {
        $("#badge-one > div").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Html

```
<input type="text"/>
<div>Hide me</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('input').val(0);

$('input').on('click',function() {
   var $input = $(this);
   $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 5); 

    if($input.val() == 10) {
         $('div').hide();   
    } else {
         $('div').show();   
    }
});
```

#### Fiddle